# Compile error with lombok in intellij - only when running build

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, lombok, intellij-lombok-plugin

I am facing a weird error when running gradle build in intellij using lombok. Lombok is not resolving getters and setters during running the build. although im not seeing any compilation error in intellij its only appearing when im running build.

Please note that

I have enabled Annotation Processing

I have installed Lombok Plugin

I have added @Data @Builder on the class

[image: annotation processors settings]

[image: Lombok plugin description]

[image: build errors image]

Answer (score 3):

I added dependencies as below and solved my problem

```
compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
```

Earlier it was just `compile 'org.projectlombok:lombok'`